# How do I add a hashtag to a custom tweet button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm trying to create a custom tweet button with a popup, this part works. However, I am unable to get it to post hashtags in the text area.

Tweet content

```
url=http://www.mywebsite.com&text=mytweetcontent&via=mytwitterusername
```

In the &text= I've experimented with using mytweetcontent+#myhashtag as well as trying the URL encoding %23 (which corresponds with #); however, I am still unable to get a hashtag to appear. Any ideas on what I can do? I would prefer to have a custom image, which is why I am not using the proprietary twitter jscript button. Thanks very much for your help!

Full code for reference:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){window.twttr=window.twttr||{};var     D=550,A=450,C=screen.height,B=screen.width,H=Math.round((B/2)-(D/2)),G=0,F=document,E;if(C>A){G=Math.round((C/2)-(A/2))}window.twttr.shareWin=window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.mywebsite.com&text=%23+mytweetcontent&via=mytwitterusername','','left='+H+',top='+G+',width='+D+',height='+A+',personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');E=F.createElement('script');E.src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';F.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(E)}());"><img src="twitter-logo.png" border="0"></a>
```

Edit* Response to comment

thanks for the suggestion! i didnt try with hashtag, just normal, but changing the & to ? removes the content area, code below. Top line is the result in the tweet box, below is corresponding url.

mycontent http://t.co/nKb4nWC via @myusername

```
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=mycontent&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&via=myusername
```

http://t.co/YzrDfzX via @myusername

```
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%3Ftext%3Dmycontent&via=myusername
```

Comment: I think (and I've not had time to test this) that the issue is with the fact that you're using `&` instead of `?` after the ".com". Browsers don't like that, it isn't well formed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with using the following?

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Text%20%23hashtag&amp;via=JohnDoe"
    onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'tweet', 'menubar=no')">
    <img src="twitter-logo.png">
</a>
```

Comment: nothing, turns out it actually works better haha, appreciate the help!

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above, but the image is static. The script above dynamically alters the button based on the content which can look nicer. See examples here: https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#mention

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo $SiteConfig->GetBaseURL(); ?>rise-challenge.php&text=Do you have what it takes to spark the rise? Click here to rise to the challenge&hashtags=sparktherise" class="socialLinkTwitter twitter" title="Twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.socialLinkTwitter').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sTwitterShare = $(this).attr('href');
        window.open(sTwitterShare,'Share','width=550,height=450');
    });
</script>
```